# php preg_replace: Replace word, even with special chars in it

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to find and replace a word like "test", but even if it has none-alphabetic chars in it, like:

```
test
t e s t
t.e.s.t
t-e-s-t
t.e-s(t
etc.
```

Any ideas how to do this in php? Perhaps with preg_replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/t\W?e\W?s\W?t/", "something", $input_array);
```

Comment: Instead of `.` shouldn't you use a non-word boundary?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will edit the answer